# VB script. Need to run below code in UFT tool

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have my below code and outer array is not comparing each value with the inner array. Outer array is comparing with the one value from the inside and moving to the next value in it.

```
testdata = {25,27,81,104,33,34,56,78,99,84}
testdata1 = {81,104}

For i = 0 To UBound(testdata) - 1

For j = 0 To UBound(testdata1) - 1
    If testdata(i) = testdata1(j) Then
       isFound = True
       Call DB_Connectionwisdataflagupdation(sQuery,Para2,Para3,Para4,sValue)
    'c=c+1
    Exit for
    End If

       'isFound = True


    isFound = False
Next 
Next
```

Please help me to get the solution on this.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from the ubound(arr)? just run the loop to ubound(arr) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I made a couple minor changes to your code, mainly adjusting the indices on your For loops:

```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim isFound As Boolean

   For i = LBound(testdata) To UBound(testdata)
      For j = LBound(testdata1) To UBound(testdata1)
          If testdata(i) = testdata1(j) Then
             isFound = True
             'Call DB_Connectionwisdataflagupdation(sQuery, Para2, Para3, Para4, sValue)
             MsgBox testdata(i)
             Exit For
          End If

          isFound = False
      Next
   Next
```